# White page, no error in Kohana

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, kohana, frame

i have a whole website written with Kohana framework, it is written not by me, I am just helping to launch it after long time, it was written in 2009 if I am right.

So, I uploaded all files, inserted Mysql data and did the configuration, I go to the website:

adress.com and it redirects to adress.com/index.php/lt

but then I see just white page, no title, nothing.
Kohana log shows:

```
    2012-08-26 22:56:48 +03:00 --- debug: Auth Library loaded
2012-08-26 22:56:48 +03:00 --- debug: MySQL Database Driver Initialized
2012-08-26 22:56:48 +03:00 --- debug: Database Library initialized
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: Global GET, POST and COOKIE data sanitized
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: Session Cookie Driver Initialized
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: Session Library initialized
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: Auth Library loaded
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: MySQL Database Driver Initialized
2012-08-26 22:56:49 +03:00 --- debug: Database Library initialize
```

Then server log shows:

```
[Sat Aug 25 12:51:47 2012] [error] [client 94.244.82.207] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.
[Sat Aug 25 12:51:48 2012] [error] [client 94.244.82.207] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.
```

Here is .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /sporttv/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Protect .git files
RewriteRule ^.git - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Look in `application/bootstrap.php` for `base_url` configuration option value. Also in your `.htaccess` ypu have `RewriteBase /sporttv/` - is this correct?

Comment: "A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path." - [mod_rewrite docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Replace the dash by "index.php/$0" to have kohana handle those and actually protect those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your `.htaccess` file. Here is working example:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /sporttv/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```